# Error: not a valid function argument name

Tags: compiler-errors, julia

Writing the program on Julia faced the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: "-2" is not a valid function argument name
```

Here is the code:

```
tic()
using JPLEphemeris
using SatelliteToolbox
using SymEngine
using DifferentialEquations
using Polynomials


fileF107 = open("C:/stj/Julia/f107.txt","r") 
linesF107 = readlines(fileF107)
spk = SPK("C:/stj/Julia/de430.bsp")
jd  = DatetoJD(2018,01,01,0,0,0) * 86400
jd2 = DatetoJD(2018,01,11,0,0,0) * 86400
sputnik_coord = [-976.3107644649057, -4835.627052558522, -5031.728586125443, -0.7944031487816871, 5.474532271429767, -5.094496750907486]
Kps = [2,1,1,1,2,1,0,4,2,0] 
h0 = 90
hx = 125
T0 = 183
M0 = 28.96
rho0 = 3.46e-12 
g = 9.8065
Ra = 6356766
R = 8.31432
req = BigFloat(6378136.3)


sun_declination_degree = [  -22.94980416,
                            -22.8593264,
                            -22.76126935,
                            -22.65568101,
                            -22.54261303,
                            -22.42212068,
                            -22.29426272,
                            -22.15910134,
                            -22.01670204,
                            -21.86713355
                        ]
c = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
c[1] = -89284375.0
c[2] = 3542400.0
c[3] = -52687.5
c[4] = 340.5
c[5] = -0.8
cstar = c
A = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
A[1] = 83809.05064
A[2] = -5196.932946
A[3] = 134.0855452
A[4] = -1.842006056
A[5] = 1.421149e-2
A[6] = -5.83912e-5
A[7] = 9.9826e-8
alpha = [
            3144902516.672729,
            -123774885.4832917,
            1816141.096520398,
            -11403.31079489267,
            24.36498612105595,
            0.008957502869707995
        ]
beta =  [
            52864482.17910969,
            16632.50847336828,
            -1.308252378125,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
        ] 
B = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

function getF107(daynum)
    stringF107 = split(linesF107[40 + daynum])
    F107 = parse(stringF107[4])
    return F107
end

function getF107a(daynum)
    sum = 0
    for day = (0:80)
        stringF107 = split(linesF107[daynum + day])
        F107 = parse(stringF107[4])
        sum = sum + F107
    end
    sum = sum / 81
    return sum
end

function getHeight(y)
    a = sqrt(y[1]^2 + y[2]^2 + y[3]^2)-Ra/1000
    return a
end

function temperature(h, date)
    date = jd2/86400

    if h < 125
        daynum = trunc(Int64,jd2/86400 - jd/86400)
        F107  = getF107(daynum)
        F107a = getF107a(daynum)
        Tc = 379 + 3.24*F107a + 1.3*(F107 - F107a)
        st_bar_sun = state(spk, 0, 10, date)
        st_bar_moon_earth = state(spk, 0, 3, date)
        st_bar_me_earth = state(spk, 3, 399, date)
        earth_solar_barycentre  =  st_bar_moon_earth + st_bar_me_earth
        sun_coord  = (st_bar_sun - earth_solar_barycentre)
        global phi_gc = y[1]/sqrt(y[1]^2+y[2]^2)
        global phi_gd = atan(tan(phi_gc)/(1 - (0.0167)^2))
        global delta = sun_declination_degree[daynum]/57.2958
        global eta = abs(phi_gd - delta)/2
        global theta = abs(phi_gd + delta)/2 
        LHA = 180/pi*(
        (y[1]*sun_coord[2] - y[2]*sun_coord[1])/(abs(y[1]*sun_coord[2] - y[2]*sun_coord[1]))*
        acos((y[1]*sun_coord[2] + y[2]*sun_coord[1])/(sqrt(y[1]^2 + y[2]^2)*sqrt(sun_coord[1]^2 + sun_coord[2]^2))))
        tau = LHA - 37 + 6*sin(LHA + 43) 
        Tunc = Tc*(1 + 0.3*(sin(theta)^2.2 + (cos(eta)^2.2 - sin(theta)^2.2)*cos(tau/2)^3)) 
    end
    Kp = Kps[daynum]
    if (h >= 200)
        deltaTcorr = 28*Kp + 0.03*exp(Kp)
    else
        deltaTcorr = 14*Kp + 0.02*exp(Kp)
    end
    global Tcorr = Tunc + deltaTcorr 
    global Tx = 371.6678 + 0.0518806*Tcorr - 294.3505*exp(-0.00216222*Tcorr)
    deltaT = 0
    for i = (1:5)
        deltaT += c[i]*h^(i - 1)
    end
    global d1 = Tx - T0
    if h < 125
        T = Tx + (d1/35^4)*deltaT 
    end
    return T    
end

function molecular_mass(y,date)

    h = 90
    if h <= 100 && h >= 90
        M = 0
        for i = 1:7
            M += A[i]*h^(i - 1)
            println("i = $i, added $(A[i]*h^(i - 1))")
        end
        return M
    end
end

y = sputnik_coord
date = jd2/86400

println(molecular_mass(y,date))

function density(y, date)
    M = molecular_mass(y, date)
    T = temperature(y, date)
    k = -g/(R*(Tx-T0))
    f = (35^4)*(Ra^2)/c[5]
    cstar[1] = 35^4 * [1 +T0/(Tx- T0)] + c[1]
    P = Poly([cstar[1],cstar[2],cstar[3],cstar[4],cstar[5]])
    roots_of_P = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    roots_of_P = roots(P)
    println(roots_of_P)
    r1 = 0
    r2 = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0

    if imag(roots_of_P[1]) == 0
        r1 = real(roots_of_P[1])
    else
        x = real(roots_of_P[1])
        y = abs(imag(roots_of_P[1]))
    end

    if imag(roots_of_P[2]) == 0
        if r1 != 0
            r2 = real(roots_of_P[2])
        else
            r1 = real(roots_of_P[2])
        end
    else
        x = real(roots_of_P[2])
        y = abs(imag(roots_of_P[2]))
    end

    if imag(roots_of_P[3]) == 0 && r1 != 0
        r2 = real(roots_of_P[3])
    elseif imag(roots_of_P[3]) == 0 && r1 == 0
        r1 = real(roots_of_P[3])
    else
        x = real(roots_of_P[3])
        y = abs(imag(roots_of_P[3]))
    end

    if imag(roots_of_P[4]) == 0
        r2 = real(roots_of_P[4])
    end

    B[1] = (A[1] - 5.04227040425412*cstar[1])*f
    B[2] = (17856541.74708379 + 0.00158642630679*cstar[1])*f107
    B[3] = (-259910.779829766 - A[7]*cstar[1]/c[5])*f
    B[4] = -1.236944975267146e17
    B[5] = 2.642300254604438e14
    B[6] = 9.740305355778338e10
    S1 = 0
    S2 = 0
    SRminus = 0
    for i = (1:6)
        S1 += B[i]*r1^(i-1) 
        S2 += B[i]*r2^(i-1)
        SRminus += B[i]*(-Ra)^(i-1)
    end

    X = -2*rl*r2*Ra*(Ra^2 + 2*x*Ra + x^2 + y^2),
    U1 = (r1 + Ra)^2 * (r1^2 - 2*x*r1 + x^2 + y^2)* (r1 - r2)
    U2 = (r2 + Ra)^2 * (r2^2 - 2*x*r2 + x^2 + y^2)* (r1 - r2)
    V =  (Ra^2 + 2*x*Ra + x^2 + y^2)*(-Ra - r1)*(-Ra - r2)
    W1 = r1*r2*(Ra^2)*(r1 + Ra) + (x^2 + y^2)*Ra*(Ra*r1 + r1r2)
    W2 = r1*r2*(Ra^2)*(r2 + Ra) + (x^2 + y^2)*Ra*(Ra*r2 + r1r2)
    p2 = S1/U1
    p3 = -S2/U2
    p5 = SRminus/V
    p4 = (B[1] - r1*r2*Ra^2* (B[5] + (2*x + r1 + r2 - Ra) *B[6]) - r1*r2*Ra*(x^2 + y^2)*B[6] + r1*r2*(Ra^2 - (x + y))*p5 + W1*p2 +W2*p3)/X
    F1 = ((h + Ra)/(h0 + Ra))^p1 *((h - r1)/(h0 - r1))^p2 * ((h - r2)/(h0 - r2))^p3 * ((h^2 - 2*x*h + x^2 +y^2)/(h0^2 - 2*x*h0 + x^2 + y^2))^p4
    p6 = B[5] + (2*x + r1 + r2 - Ra)*B[6] - p5 - 2*(x + Ra)*p4 - (r2 + Ra)*p3 - (r1 + Ra)*p2
    p1 = B[6] - 2*p4 - p3 -p2
    F1 = ((h+Ra)/(h0+Ra))^p1 *((h-r1)/(h0-r1))^p2 *((h-r2)/(h0-r2))^p3 *(((h^2)-2*x*h + x^2 +y^2)/((h0^2)-2*x*h0 + x^2 +y^2))^p4
    F2 = (h-h0)*(f*A[7] + p5/((h + Ra)*(h0 + Ra))) + p6/y *atan((y*(h-h0))/(y^2+(h-x)*(h0-x)))
    rho = rho0*(F1^k)*exp(k*F2)*((M*T0)/(M0*T)) 
    return rho
end
toc()
```

After commenting the `density` function, the error disappeared, therefore, the error is in this function. I found this [issue](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/issues/339) with the similar problem, but it could not resolve the problem. I looked for -2 in the code but it seems to me that this is not the actual reason. The only part which seems suspicious to me and(as I suppose) can contain a mistake is the row where the `F1` is calculated. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the error, in the part where `X` is calculated:

`X = -2*rl*r2*Ra*(Ra^2 + 2*x*Ra + x^2 + y^2),`

No comma is needed here.

Comment: just curious- how did you end up funding that it was a comma from that unhelpful error message?